# Uniswap - How to delete a pair created with price set incorrecly?

Tags: uniswap

How to delete a Uniswap pair created with price set incorrectly?
I created new pair for token but it went wrong, and set price too high. How to delete it to start over?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to delist trading pairs from the Uniswap exchange.

What you can do is to add a little bit of liquidity (as much as you're willing to lose) to the pair, and then manipulate the price via swaps to reach the correct target price. (If this is Uniswap v2, then some small amount of liquidity always is guaranteed to be present in the pool after the first add.) Either do the swap yourself or, if the liquidity in the pool is sufficiently deep, arbitrage bots will do the swapping for you (at your loss, obviously).

Comment: Thank Yo for your answer. Other problem I have is when I create that pair, it not allow me to add my token to pool, only USDC pair. What could be wrong ? looks like something is wrong with token itself. I did try same things on other website like pancS. I have error that I need create start price first, but when I try to do that, eg set min price of ftoken and then go to window with USDC when I type in ... amout from My token desapear and vice versa ?

Comment: @Yaro If the price in the pool is outside the price range of the position you want to add, then just one of the tokens can be added. But if the pool's price is in the range, and you still can't add the positions (transaction reverts) then something could be wrong with your token, we can't know that